# SIGSEGV at somewhere should not be, there's no NULL pointer

Tags: c, linux, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I use `gdb test core` and get this:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000557ce64b63f8 in _create (str=str@entry=0x557ce80a8820 "SEND")
    at system.c:708
708         data->res = command->data->res;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000557ce64b63f8 in _create (str=str@entry=0x557ce80a8820 "SEND")
    at system.c:708
#1  0x0000557ce64b2ef1 in make_command (s=<optimized out>, cmd=0x557ce809cb70) at command.c:121
#2  0x0000557ce63aefdf in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fff19053278) at main.c:394
(gdb) p *command
$1 = {status = 1, data = 0x7f21027e9a80, sum = 1543465568, time = 0, msg = { str = 0x7f20fd19f080 "GOOD", len = 4}, id = 2}
(gdb) p *command->data
$2 = {status = 1, item = 0x7f21027eb780, res = 0x7f2100990b00, sum = 1133793665}
(gdb) p *command->data->res
$3 = {msg = { str = 0x7f21010a5500 "Hi, test, test"..., len = 14}, status = 1}
(gdb) p *data
$4 = {status = 1, type = 5, res = 0x0, id = 2}
```

as you can see, the pointer `command` and `command->data` and `data` are all valid, why this SIGSEGV happened?

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: I would like to , but the project is too big, I just do not know where is the problem. If I can create a minimal , complete, verifiable code, then I should already know the cause..

Comment: That's the point!! Please read [ask], but you should already know this. :)

Comment: A pointer doesn't have to be null to be invalid.

Comment: suggest: use gdb to run the program. when it seg faults, then enter the command `bt` to get the exact point where the program fails.

Comment: @user3629249 To be fair, that is what OP already did...

Comment: *the pointer `command` and `command->data` and `data` are all valid*  To put it clearly, they're **not** known to be valid.  They're known to be non-zero.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

> why this SIGSEGV happened?

We can't tell.

One possible reason: some *other* code is actually executing and crashing.

This could happen if `system.c` has been edited or updated, but the program has not been rebuilt with the new source. Or if the compiler mapping of program counter to file/line is inaccurate (this often happens with optimized code).

If you edit your question to show the output from `list _create`, `disas $pc` and `info registers`, we may be able to tell you more.